# php session, на каждой странице отображаются разные значения

Tags: php, сессия, kohana

Использую фреймворк Kohana 3.3.
Использую сессии для выбора города. Однако не так давно стала происходить магия.

Выбираю город (всё хорошо). Перехожу на другую страницу, отображается другое значение.

Вот так задаю город для сессии.

```
Session::instance()->set('city', $query['city']);
```

Видео процесса неправильной работы сессии. http://take.ms/IARiQ

Comment: а что в сессии на другой странице находиться?

Comment: @Naumov сессия задаётся в контроллере, который подключается ко всем контроллером на сайте. Сессия города задаётся в функции before()